# Change many symbolic links at once?

Tags: shell-script, symbolic-link

I have about 40 symbolic links in a directory that look like this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 anna  staff    45B 22 Jun 11:20 menu-bg-left.jpg -> ../../../../../hg/www/images/menu-bg-left.jpg
lrwxr-xr-x    1 anna  staff    46B 22 Jun 11:20 menu-bg-right.jpg -> ../../../../../hg/www/images/menu-bg-right.jpg
```

I would like to change them all to a different directory:

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 anna  staff    45B 22 Jun 11:20 menu-bg-left.jpg -> ../../../../../code-local/www/images/menu-bg-left.jpg
lrwxr-xr-x    1 anna  staff    46B 22 Jun 11:20 menu-bg-right.jpg -> ../../../../../code-local/www/images/menu-bg-right.jpg
```

For various reasons I can't just symlink the `hg` directory to the `code-local` directory, I need to change the links themselves.

Can I shell script this somehow?

Answer (score 2):

You change dir to the directory where you want your sym-links to be placed. Then you read all your images from the source directory in a for loop. With every run of the loop a sym-link is created.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /to/directory/where/symlinks/should/be/*
do
   rm $file
   ln -s /where/your/image/files/are/$(basename $file) $file
done
```

Comment: No sorry, it's not that simple. I have directory X with many images and some symlinks. I have directory Y with many, many images. I want to *update* the existing symlinks in X to point to Y (not add new symlinks as would happen if I listed all the images in Y).

Comment: i've edited the code, so the for loop now read the dir with the existing symlinks, than removes the first one, creates it again with the new path and so on and on. I think this is now what you need?

Comment: 'fraid not, directory X has many images and some symlinks, I only want to replace the symlinks. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Modify to use `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …` you can tell it to only find symlinks. You can even add extra filters in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `readlink` and shell, something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /to/directory/where/symlinks/should/be
for i in * ; do
    if [ -h $i ]; then
        NEWTARGET=`readlink $i | sed 's,old/path/to/files,new/path/to/files,'`
        rm -f $i
        ln -s $NEWTARGET $i
    fi
done
```